# Selecting variables in a multivariate regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am quite new to R and I am having trouble figuring out how to select variables in a multivariate linear regression in R.

Pretend I have the following formulas:

```
P = aX + bY
Q = cZ + bY
```

I have a data frame with column P, Q, X, Y, Z and I need to find a, b and c.

If I do a simple multivariate regression:

```
result <- lm( cbind( P, Q ) ~ X + Y + Z - 1 )
```

It calculates a coefficient for "c" on P's regression and for "a" on Q's regression.

If I calculate the regressions individually then "b" will be different in each regression.

How can I select the variables to consider in a multivariate regression?

Thank you, 
Edson

Comment: I think you need SEM to do that... in lavaan syntax this would be straightforward

Comment: Can you show me how to do that with lavaan? reading the tutorial, but still not clear to me.

Comment: I **think** you can still use  `anova` command (manova) to fit mlm models. John Fox wrote a quick guide on fitting these models that might help - "Multivariate Linear Models in R"

Comment: I also think you may get a better response on Crossvalidated [http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ] as this is a statistical question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The solution proposed by @lebatsnok worked well and since my actual problem uses several additional variables (15 independent, 11 dependent), the syntax he demonstrated will simplify the definition of the model quite a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> P = aX + bY; 
>   Q = cZ + bY

in lavaan you could do it by adding an equality constraint i.e giving two parameters the same custom name

```
P ~ X + b*Y
Q ~ Z + b*Y
```

See also http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax2.html